# What's normal Taskbar behavior (windows)

Tags: windows-vista, taskbar

I'm a fairly new user to windows, and Vista is my first version. I'm a bit confused about the taskbar -- either its behaving oddly or I'm just confused, or I've broken something.

When I've got a lot of windows on screen, I thought that clicking on a window's taskbar icon would bring that window to the front. I thought it had been doing that in the past, but I'm not entirely sure.

When I click it, it just flashes, a second click minimized, and a third click reopens and brings it to the front.

Is this normal?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes one gets a funny behavior when minimizing all programs to the taskbar by using Alt-M or Alt-D, where the programs don't un-minimize correctly. It can sometimes take some effort to un-minimize a program that doesn't want to be restored.

Sometimes, the only way to reach a minimized window is to use the Alt-Tab mechanism.
Other times, one has to use Alt-M or Alt-D repeatedly until the problem goes away.

This is a Microsoft bug in the implementation of the taskbar that one has to live with.
Windows is a very complex operating system, and not all its developpers were thorough enough.

Comment: Though I agree, I would add that some of the blame for programs that operate like this should be placed on the developers of the individual applications.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes Windows can be a bit finnicky.  Especially in Windows XP, though the Vista taskbar is also similar.  Sometimes even though you clicked on a button for a program and it's depressed, the window does not show up.  I think it's because it automatically hides it or puts it under other windows through some glitch.  However, clicking it again will put the program in the background, and then clicking a third time will once again try to bring it up front.  Usually that's all that needs to be done.

It is normal but one of those weird issues that happens now and then.  You may find similar weird things like this however they aren't common enough to make it difficult to use.  It probably was a glitch that Microsoft didn't catch in testing, or was unable to reproduce so they couldn't track down a fix for it.

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/139024-taskbar-group-similar-buttons.html